# Cassandra: Inserting value in UDT

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to insert values in UDT but getting error message -

```
 message="unconfigured columnfamily my_object"
```

below my statement-

```
INSERT INTO home.my_object (id,type,quantity ,critical,page_count,stock,outer_envelope ) VALUES ('3.MYF','COM','D','A','VV','','');
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: the column family doesn't exist? Can you also write your CREATE Statement?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the keyspace "home" exists, but does not contain a table (column family) called "my_object". I also noticed that your insert statement does not contain a UDT literal.

UDTs define a type, but you must also define a table with a column of that type before inserting any data. I assume your UDT is called "my_object". Try this:

```
create table home.test (key int primary key, object frozen<my_object>);
insert into home.test (key, object) values (0, {id: 'value', type: 'othervalue'});
```